# React Grid Layout Overlapping Items

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-grid-layout

How do I create a `react-grid-layout` with 100 grid points `width` and specify the width of the grid items in this so that they don't overlap?

[image]

(Note: reducing number of columns fixes this overlap issue, but then I don't have the 100 point resolution in width for grid placement)

```
import Button, { ButtonProps } from '@mui/material/Button';
import GridLayout from 'react-grid-layout';

const TempButton = (props: ButtonProps) => (
  <Button
    {...props}
    variant="outlined"
    sx={{
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
        opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
      },
    }}
  />
);

export const DeckLayout = (props: any) => {
  const layout = [
    {
      i: '1',
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: 2,
      h: 2,
    },
    {
      i: '2',
      x: 2,
      y: 0,
      w: 1,
      h: 1,
    },
    {
      i: '3',
      x: 3,
      y: 0,
      w: 2,
      h: 3,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={100} rowHeight={10} width={500}>
      <div key="1">
        <TempButton>1</TempButton>
      </div>
      <div key="2">
        <TempButton>2</TempButton>
      </div>
      <div key="3">
        <TempButton>3</TempButton>
      </div>
    </GridLayout>
  );
};
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-example-fvpkcl?file=/src/layout.tsx)

Edit: seems like it might be something with the CSS? when I modify the stock example it performs as expected:

[image: stock layout]

here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stock-react-grid-layout-100cols-vlpelp?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As posted [here](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/issues/710#issuecomment-1219713768), in order to get exact `grid unit` to pixel mapping, you need to set `margin={[0,0]}`

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-example-no-margin-ighkli?file=/src/layout.tsx)

---

Yep, combination of `css` and thinking issues:

- MaterialUI has a default `minWidth` of `64px` for a button.
- It seems the width of the columns are calculated as (`Gridlayout` `width`) / (`Gridlayout` `cols`). So in the above example the column width is `500px`/ `100 cols` = `5 px/col` <<< `minWidth = 64px`

Fix:

<strike>`width: 100%`</strike>

<strike>`height: 100%`</strike>

```
<GridLayout
   className="layout"
   layout={layout}
   cols={100}
   rowHeight={10}
   width={6400}
>
```

[image]

Full fix:

```
import Button, { ButtonProps } from "@mui/material/Button";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";

const TempButton = (props: ButtonProps) => (
  <Button
    {...props}
    variant="outlined"
    sx={{
      padding: 0,
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "primary.dark",
        opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7]
      }
    }}
  />
);

export const DeckLayout = (props: any) => {
  const layout = [
    {
      i: "1",
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: 2,
      h: 2
    },
    {
      i: "2",
      x: 2,
      y: 0,
      w: 1,
      h: 1
    },
    {
      i: "3",
      x: 3,
      y: 0,
      w: 2,
      h: 3
    }
  ];

  return (
    <GridLayout
      className="layout"
      layout={layout}
      cols={100}
      rowHeight={10}
      width={6400}
    >
      <div key="1">
        <TempButton>1</TempButton>
      </div>
      <div key="2">
        <TempButton>2</TempButton>
      </div>
      <div key="3">
        <TempButton>3</TempButton>
      </div>
    </GridLayout>
  );
};
```

and [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-example-fixed-7l2www?file=/src/layout.tsx:0-999)